# How to define references when one poco/table has a composite primary key

Tags: c#, .net, ormlite-servicestack

Considering the documentation [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite), you can define foreign key relationships in your pocos like the given example:

```
public class Customer
{
    [References(typeof(CustomerAddress))]
    public int PrimaryAddressId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public CustomerAddress PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
}
```

However, let's say that my `CustomerAddress` poco class actually has to be defined like this because someone decided to design the table like this a long, long time ago.

```
public class CustomerAddress
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id_1 { get; set; }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id_2 { get; set; }
}
```

How can I properly define my `[Reference]` for the `PrimaryAddress` property in the `Customer` class with the composite key defined in `CustomerAddress`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't using APIs that rely on it (but you can still use `SELECT`)
Please see [OrmLite limitations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#limitations).

I had same problem with a legacy database I can't modify (because another project cohabit with mine).
So I deleted primary key then created a new `Id` field (autoincrement) on the database (PK) and finally created a unique constraint (NOT NULLABLE) on both fields.

So now, I can use OrmLite to select properly without breaking compatibility with the other project.